# How do I get systemctl to print in color when being interacted with from a non-tty?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, tty, watch, systemctl

When I run a command like this:

```
# systemctl status plexmediaserver
```

I get nicely colored output. But when I run the following command:

```
# watch -n300 --color systemctl status plexmediaserver
```

Is there any way I can do this `watch` command with color from `systemctl`? I've looked at the man page for `systemctl` but do not see reference to color anywhere.

Comment: Please consider accepting towolf's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1196178/664) which is much better than currently accepted one (yours). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
watch -c  SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 systemctl status icinga2
```

`man systemd` says

```
   $SYSTEMD_COLORS
       Controls whether colorized output should be generated.
```

i.e., you can force color mode with that.

Comment: … and of course, by now `SYSTEMD_COLORS` does more than the name suggests, because mid 2018 support for clickable links got introduced, littering output with some escape codes and urlified URLs – which fortunately can be turned off with `SYSTEMD_URLIFY=0`

Answer (score 28):

`systemctl` does not appear to have a mechanism for specifying when to color the output. A quick solution would be to shim `isatty(3)` to always return true, thus tricking `systemctl` into thinking stdout is interactive. Namely you could do:

```
# echo "int isatty(int fd) { return 1; }" | gcc -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o isatty.so -xc -
# LD_PRELOAD=./isatty.so watch -n300 --color systemctl status plexmediaserver
```

The `-xc -` at the end of the `gcc` command tells `gcc` to compile C code (`-xc`) from stdin (`-`). The rest of the flags tell `gcc` to create a shared object file named `isatty.so`. Note that this could very well break other programs which rely on `isatty` to return a legitimate value. It however appears to be fine for `systemctl` as `isatty` appears to be solely used for the purpose of determining if it should color its output.

Comment: This is brilliant. I built a [script to automate the process](https://superuser.com/a/1245671/365890).

Comment: After I read and voted towolf's answer (which is much better than this one) up I was going to downvote this but this is too perfect a hack so instead I'm voting this up with somehow mixed feelings :)

Comment: You genius, it works with the clang-tidy color output issue with cmake, brilliant!!!

Answer (score 5):

Based on [@KarlC's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1042176/365890), here is a script which generates and then includes the library at runtime:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

function clean_up {
  trap - EXIT # Restore default handler to avoid recursion
  [[ -e "${isatty_so:-}" ]] && rm "$isatty_so"
}
# shellcheck disable=2154 ## err is referenced but not assigned
trap 'err=$?; clean_up; exit $err' EXIT HUP INT TERM

isatty_so=$(mktemp --tmpdir "$(basename "$0")".XXXXX.isatty.so)
echo "int isatty(int fd) { return 1; }" \
  | gcc -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o "$isatty_so" -xc -
# Allow user to SH=/bin/zsh faketty mycommand
"${SH:-$SHELL}" -c 'eval $@' - LD_PRELOAD="$isatty_so" "$@"
```

Comment: ...what a hack 