# Keep Color output with grep at systemctl status

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to get the original color of the output of this command with grep:

`sudo systemctl status telegraf | grep -e ● -e Active`

[Output of command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdHvU.png)

with this command the output is red, but i want it to match the original color, which is in this case green when the service is active and red or no color when its inactive.

I tried as described here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75527/how-can-i-keep-color-codes-with-grep-input, but this does seem to work only with ls command.

`sudo systemctl status telegraf --color=always | grep --color=never -e ● -e Active`

This throws an error: `systemctl: unrecognized option '--color=always'`

This of course has no color at all: `sudo systemctl status telegraf | grep --color=never -e ● -e Active`

It would be great if someone knew what I could do to achieve the original color output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (systemd 244.5+): using the --no-pager option to any systemctl commands seems to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you observe red, it comes from `grep`. You can (and did) turn this off with `grep --color=never …`. Neither this red nor `--color=never` of `grep` overrides some green generated by `systemctl`. The point is there is no green when `systemctl` prints to a pipe; this is the main issue here.

If you managed to make `systemctl` print green to a pipe, then your `grep --color=never …` would not alter the color.

There is a way. I took it from [this answer to a somewhat similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1196178/432690).

```
sudo SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 systemctl status telegraf | grep --color=never -e ● -e Active
```

The other question does not involve `sudo`. In your case `sudo` may interfere. It may or may not allow you to set a variable (or the variable) in the above way. It may or may not allow you to pass it this other way:

```
SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 sudo -E systemctl status telegraf | grep --color=never -e ● -e Active
```

See `man 8 sudo` and `man 5 sudoers` where they mention the environment. It may be your `sudo` is configured to sanitize the environment no matter what; in such case try this:

```
sudo sh -c 'SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 systemctl status telegraf' | grep --color=never -e ● -e Active
```

Do you really need `sudo` to invoke `systemctl status …`? Maybe you can simply do this without `sudo`:

```
SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 systemctl status telegraf | grep --color=never -e ● -e Active
```